# Trying to copy data values to another sheet Lastrow error

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I'm trying to copy some data to a different sheet using the following code:

```
Sub FilterButton()
    Dim SourceRange As Range, DestRange As Range
    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet, Lr As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'fill in the Source Sheet and range
    Set SourceRange = Sheets("Imported Data").Range("A1:K1")

    'Fill in the destination sheet and call the LastRow
    'function to find the last row
    Set DestSheet = Sheets("Test")
    Lr = lastRow(DestSheet)

    'With the information from the LastRow function we can
    'create a destination cell
    Set DestRange = DestSheet.Range("A" & Lr + 1)

    'Copy the source range and use PasteSpecial to paste in
    'the destination cell
    SourceRange.Copy
    DestRange.PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, _
            skipblanks:=False, _
            Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
```

Only when I try to do it, I get the following error: Compile error: Sub or Function not defined (this error points to the lastRow)... how Can I fix this?

Edited:

```
   Sub FilterButton()
    Dim SourceRange As Range, SRange, DestRange, myMultipleRange As Range
    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet, Lr As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'fill in the Source Sheets and ranges
    Set SourceRange = Sheets("Imported Data").Range("A2:B:C")
    Set SRange = Sheets("Imported Data").Range("E2:E8")
    Set myMultipleRange = Union(SourceRange, SRange)

    'Fill in the destination sheet and find the last known cell
    Set DestSheet = Sheets("Test")

    'With the information on the new sheet
    Set DestRange = DestSheet.Range("A:B:C:E")

    'Copy the source range and use PasteSpecial to paste in
    'the destination cell
    myMultipleRange.Copy
    DestRange.PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, _
            skipblanks:=False, _
            Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

These ranges I want, but I can't use the range on multiple selections :(!

Comment: the error message is correct. what in your opinion is `lastRow`??

Comment: The lastrow is the lastrow that contains data in the sheet. So if cell A14 has the last known data I want to copy everything till that row

Comment: No, it's not. There is nothing like instruction or command in VBA named 'lastrow'. This is possibly a function which someone made and you need to have it in your project, too. Therefore you need to go back to the source of your code and search for 'lastrow function' and copy it to your project.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using lastrow but get the last known datacell in my worksheet(got this code from a colleague but he can't find the original function)

Comment: see proposed solution in answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be lot's of possible substitution of your `LastRow` function. You could try with this option:

instead of your line:

```
Lr = lastRow(DestSheet)
```

put this one:

```
Lr = DestSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

Comment: One last question, the code works copying the entire row..:

Set SourceRange = Sheets("Imported Data").Range("A2:E8")

I now want only the column A,B,C and E to be copied. Is that possible adding a few lines in this code or do I need another code structure?

Comment: Hmm, I can't see line of code you refer to but I see A1:K1 range which is copied. But any of this copies the entire row (or the code in your question is incomplete). Try manipulate with ranges inside quotation marks. Or check your code carefully and show complete of it for further help.

Comment: Thanks :) Just updated the entire code I know have with the given question.. hope u can help me.

Comment: is this line of your code working: `myMultipleRange.Copy`? you are trying to copy non-continuous range there which is not allowed. I still can't see you trying to copy-paste entire row. You need to carefully analyse the logic you create the following ranges: `SourceRange, SRange,  myMultipleRange` which looks strange to me but could be correct due to your sheet layout.

Comment: I've got it now, thanks for all your help! I'll post my answer

Answer (score 0):

Does this function actually exist? It is not a default function in VBA, so you must have created your own function!

So the next questions are:

1. Did you create a `Function` called `lastRow(args1)`?
2. Did you really create a `Function` and not by accident a `Sub`?
3. Does the `Function` exist in the same `Module`, and if not is it `Public` (so other modules can use it)?

Answer (score 0):

Sub FilterButton()
    Dim SourceRange As Range, DestRange As Range
    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet, Lr As Long
    Dim ColumnRange As Range

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'fill in the Source Sheet and range
Set SourceRange = Sheets("Imported Data").Range("A:C,E:E")

'Fill in the destination sheet and find the last known cell
Set DestSheet = Sheets("Test")

'With the information on the new sheet
Set DestRange = DestSheet.Range("A:E")

'Copy the source range and use PasteSpecial to paste in
'the destination cell
SourceRange.Copy
DestRange.PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, _
        skipblanks:=False, _
        Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

have only just seen your question, a bit belated I know.I am not sure if you are aware but the code you are using is an exact replica of Ron de Bruin's examples given in his link

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win001.htm

for an elegant exposition take a look at the various examples.
See particularly at the bottom of his section for an explanation of the functions you need to include in your code ( such as 'LastRow function' etc. - the comments in your code refer to this function... ).

I quote :

Important: The macro examples use one function or more than one of the functions that you can find in the last section of this page. Do not forget to copy the functions in your workbook a Standard module of your workbook, if you just started with VBA see this page.
Where do I paste the code that I find on the internet